# Using only one function to update different columns of a table in database

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, in-place-editor

```
id  car         make          sales
 1  panamera    porsche       100 
 2  italia      ferrari       200
 3  volante     astonmartin   300
 4  avantador   lamborghini   400
 5  slk         mercedes      500
```

So guys, i have this simple table in my database. And i'm gonna echo this table in a while loop.

```
<ul>
<?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM inplace LIMIT 0, 6";    
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Query couldn\'t be executed');  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<li class="editable" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['car'].'</li>';
echo '<li class="editable2" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['make'].'</li>'; 
}
?>
</ul>
```

The idea is to update this table using jQuery in-place editor. So here is the code-

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$(".editable").bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);
$(".editable2").bind("dblclick", replaceHTML2);
$(".btnSave, .btnDiscard").live("click", handler);

function handler()
    {

        if ($(this).hasClass("btnSave"))
            {

                var str = $(this).siblings("form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "handler.php",
                        data: str,
                }); 

            }

    } 

function replaceHTML()
    {
        var buff = $(this).html()
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
        $(this).addClass("noPad")
                .html("<form><input type=\"text\" name=\"car\" value=\"" + buff + "\" /> <input type=\"text\" name=\"buffer\" value=\"" + buff + "\" /><input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" value=\"" + $(this).attr("id") + "\" /></form><a href=\"#\" class=\"btnSave\">Save changes</a> <a href=\"#\" class=\"btnDiscard\">Discard changes</a>")
                .unbind('dblclick', replaceHTML);   


    }

    function replaceHTML2()
    {
        var buff = $(this).html()
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
        $(this).addClass("noPad")
                .html("<form><input type=\"text\" name=\"make\" value=\"" + buff + "\" /> <input type=\"text\" name=\"buffer\" value=\"" + buff + "\" /><input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" value=\"" + $(this).attr("id") + "\" /></form><a href=\"#\" class=\"btnSave\">Save changes</a> <a href=\"#\" class=\"btnDiscard\">Discard changes</a>")
                .unbind('dblclick', replaceHTML);   


    }

}
);
```

This is an in-place edit code i got it from the internet and i just tore it down to basic level just to understand the codes. Dont worry bout the update query, its is in "handler.php".
The problem here is, i have to write separate function for each column. In this case, i have to write a separate function to update 'car' column, separate function to update 'make' column and goes on. I dont think this is the correct method to do. Because, here i just have 3 columns. What if i had 10 to 15 columns? I dont think writing 15 functions is the correct method. And "$(this).html()" takes only one form's value. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your PHP script to generate HTML similar to this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr data-id="1">
        <td data-col="car">panamera</td>
        <td data-col="make">porsche</td>
        <td data-col="sales">100</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</tbody>
```

The `id` of the database row corresponding to each HTML table row is specified with `data-id` in each `tr`. And each `td` specifies to which DB column it corresponds using `data-col`.

Using these information you can pass enough information back to the PHP script that updates the database. So essentially when a cell is clicked, you can get its column name using:

```
$(this).data('col')
```

And you can get the ID for its row using:

```
$(this).parent('tr').data('id')
```

Then you can pass these to the PHP page that updates the DB.

#### EDIT 1:

You can use `ul/li` instead of `table/tr/td`. You can also use `class=car, class=make, etc.` instead of `data-col='car', data-col='make', etc.` if you are using an older version of jQuery that does not support HTML5-style `data-` attributes.

#### EDIT 2: Complete solution

Change your `while` loop to this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<li class="editable" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" data-col="car">'.$row['car'].'</li>';
    echo '<li class="editable" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" data-col="make">'.$row['make'].'</li>'; 
}
```

As you can see we store the database row ID in `data-id` and the database column name in `data-col`.

Now with this setup you would only need one handler:

```
function replaceHTML()
{
    var rowId   = $(this).data('id');
    var colName = $(this).data('col');
    var buff = $(this).html().replace(/"/g, "&quot;"); // Are you sure you need this?
    $(this).addClass("noPad")
            .html("<form><input type=\"text\" name=\"" + colName + "\" value=\"" + buff + "\" /> <input type=\"text\" name=\"buffer\" value=\"" + buff + "\" /><input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" value=\"" + rowId + "\" /></form><a href=\"#\" class=\"btnSave\">Save changes</a> <a href=\"#\" class=\"btnDiscard\">Discard changes</a>")
            .unbind('dblclick', replaceHTML);   
}

$(".editable").bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);
```

**Finally**, always try to write readable code! Please! :)

#### EDIT 3: JSFiddle

Please see [this live solution](http://jsfiddle.net/JWLuA/). It shows how you can get the column name and row ID. You just have to adopt it to work with your PHP script.

Comment: Hi Behrang Saeedzadeh, u meant to say instead of $(this).html(), i have to use $(this).data()?

Comment: No, I just laid out the general approach. Google for jQuery HTML5 data attributes for more information regarding data attributes.

Comment: Hi  Behrang Saeedzadeh, firstly i thank you for your answer. I hope u got what that function "replaceHTML" does. The "buff" what i have used is a buffer thing which stores the previous value. In that form, the first input stores the database value, second one stores the buffer value(as input type="hidden"), third one stores the id value(as input type="hidden"). But when i used your code and inspected the element in chrome, the "name" for the first input comes as "undefined" instead of "car" or "make" and the "value" for the third input comes as "undefined" instead of "1" or "2" or "3"..

Comment: @generalsagar You are welcome General! ;) Also the logic behind your code is clear and readable. The indenting as well as the length of the lines are not that ideal. Makes reading it kind of difficult. Please see the updated solution!

Comment: Hi Behrang Saeedzadeh, thanks for your solution. It worked. But the problem is, i have to use it only for <a> tag. If i use it for <li> or any other, it reads as "undefined".